# Rebobinar vídeo HTML5 após clique sem aceleração ou lag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, vídeo

**O que preciso**

Preciso de um script (Javascript, jQuery, etc) para rebobinar um vídeo após clicar. Utilizei um script que encontrei em alguns fóruns, mas ele rebobina o vídeo com aceleração, o que faz com que a animação fique ruim/estranha. Precisaria ser na mesma velocidade.

**O que tenho**

```
//[Rewind]  

var video = document.getElementById('video');
var intervalRewind;
jQuery(video).on('play',function(){
        video.playbackRate = 1.0;
        clearInterval(intervalRewind);
});
jQuery(video).on('pause',function(){
        video.playbackRate = 1.0;
        clearInterval(intervalRewind);
});
jQuery("#btnVoltar").click(function() { // button function for rewind
     intervalRewind = setInterval(function(){
             video.playbackRate = 1.0;
             if(video.currentTime == 0){
                     clearInterval(intervalRewind);
                     video.pause();
             }
             else{
                     video.currentTime += -.1;
             }
                        },30);
});
```

Comment: Tenta mudar o interval do setInterval para 100 ao invés de 30 e veja se funciona (na ultima parte do código, após o else `else{
                     video.currentTime += -.1;
             }
                        },100); `

Answer (score 0):

Então, a aceleração acontece porque [de onde você copiou](https://codepen.io/adrianparr/pen/qmCek), esse me parece ser o objetivo. Se você quer um rewind como um "play reverso" você precisa casar o tamanho do intervalo com o fator de subtração. E ainda observar outros detalhes como o framerate e carregamento do video para entregar uma melhor experiência.

```js
//[Rewind]  
$(document).ready(function() {

  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  var intervalRewind;
  $("#video").on('play', function() {
    video.playbackRate = 1.0;
    clearInterval(intervalRewind);
    //console.log('playing');
  });
  jQuery(video).on('pause', function() {
    video.playbackRate = 1.0;
    clearInterval(intervalRewind);
  });
  jQuery("#btnVoltar").click(function() { // button function for rewind
    clearInterval(intervalRewind);
    
    
    intervalRewind = setInterval(function() {
      
     // video.playbackRate = 1.0;
      if (video.currentTime <= 0) {
        video.pause();
        clearInterval(intervalRewind);
         
      } else {        
         video.currentTime -= .06;
         
      }
     // console.clear();
     //console.log(video.currentTime);
    }, 60);
    
  });
  
  video.pause();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="video" controls width="50%">
 <source src="https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 <p>Your browser does not support H.264/MP4.</p>
</video>

<button id="btnVoltar">Voltar</button>
```

Comment: Entendi! Muito obrigado. Vou fazer alguns testes e tentar alinhar o FPS, o intervalo e o fator de subtração. Além disso, tenho outra dúvida: se for utilizar múltiplos vídeos em uma página (algo entre 7 ou 8), tem alguma forma otimizada de conseguir controlar esses rewinds distintos?

Comment: @GuilhermeXavier, Outra coisa interessante seria mutar o video no rewind, não entendi a sua segunda dúvida, você tem cerca de 7 a 8 videos distintos sendo executados simultaneamente?

Comment: acabei conseguindo resolver! Desculpe pela demora. Os vídeos não eram simultâneos não. Eles só estavam presentes na mesma página, mas era disparado 1 por vez a partir de um clique (o mesmo para o rewind). Muito obrigado pelo help!